# Why are rocket launches so loud?

Tags: launch, rockets, exhaust

In reading an answer here: [How close can I get to a rocket launch and not get killed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6587/how-close-can-i-get-to-a-rocket-launch-and-not-get-killed?rq=1), the comment is made that noise from the launch can be tremendous.  This isn't a big surprise to anyone who's watched a launch on video, or especially has had the privilege of watching one live.  So, fundamentally, why are rocket launches so loud?  What components of a rocket motor firing contribute to the tremendous noise?  I understand that a tremendous amount of energy is being expended in a very short timeframe and concentrated area (rocket nozzle).

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine_nozzle) indicates that a typical nozzle velocity is 2802 m/s, which is around Mach 8.  I'm sure the shock wave of that nozzle velocity (and the 2.8 km/sec escape exhaust velocity) is a significant contributor to the noise, but are there other significant contributors to launch noise?

Comment: At some level this is simply an inevitable result of the second law of thermodynamics. A rocket engine is a type of heat engine, and the second law implies a strict limit on the efficiency of heat engines. That means some energy must be wasted. If that waste energy is generated, where is it going to go? Sound waves efficiently and rapidly transport energy away.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Prediction of Acoustic Loads Generated by Propulsion Systems](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110012036.pdf)

> The  primary  noise  source  during  rocket  engine  testing  is  the 
>   jet  noise  generated  by  the  rocket  exhaust  plume .  The  jet 
>   noise  is  produced  directly  from  the  formation,  propagation  and
>   dissipation  of  vortices  or  eddies  that  are  formed in the shear
>   layer of the plume. These eddies are very small in size near the
>   nozzle exit where they originally  form  and  as  they  propagate 
>   along  the  plume  they  become  larger  until  they  eventually 
>   dissipate.  Once  the  sound  waves  that  are  created  from  the 
>   eddies  begin  to  propagate  through  the  air  and  spread  out 
>   over  an  area  they  create  pressure  changes  that  will  then  be 
>   picked  up  by  the  microphones.  Since  these  sound  waves  vary 
>   in  frequency,  a  spectrum  of  varying  sound  pressure  levels 
>   will  be  generated  along  the  length  of  the  plume.

[image]