# Rocket engine power vs. Sound

Tags: propulsion, fuel, engine-design

Is there any relationship between the sound emitted from a rocket engine and the amount of thrust it gets at surface temperature and pressure?

Comment: related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/why-are-rocket-launches-so-loud

Comment: In theory a rocket with two engines of the same type will be 3 dB louder than the rocket with only one. 5 engines will 7 dB louder.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes!  I've heard the relationship referred to as "acoustic efficiency" (i.e. how much of the power of the rocket essentially makes sound).

I don't have a lot of experience in the relevant areas, but [this NTRS paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19990040528.pdf) has some references that might let you explore the question.  (Bonus for space archaeologists:  as late as 1999 (which I infer from the reference dates and the URL) NASA was producing electronic copies of papers by printing them out (probably from Word) and re-scanning them...skewed.)

Comment: May be they lost the file of the paper but not the printout. In an old book about Word97 problem solving I found nothing about printing to a PDF file instead of a hardware printer.