# Explosion at the launch pad and safe distance from it

Tags: rockets, debris, shockwave, rocket-explosion

As the rocket explodes at the launch pad, heat wave, sound wave and debris spread around the launch pad. So in case

How the safe zone is determined in the case of explosion of the rocket at launch pad?

With respect to solar radiation calculation form [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6587/how-close-can-i-get-to-a-rocket-launch-and-not-get-killed#8724) I came to know some distance, but for sound wave and debris I am not able to get anything.

For debris rage calculation, I thought of modelling a 1 kg block of metal is provided all the energy and then see it's projectile at 45$^0$ angle. Is it a good model for the debris range calculation?